# C++ inheritance accessing protected data members

Tags: c++, inheritance

Can a child of a class access the data members of an object of the derived class?

For example, I have this code.

```
class word
{
protected:
    char * a_word;
    word * next;
};

class texting : public word
{
public:
    word * checkPhrase(char * token, word * curr);
};

word * texting::checkPhrase(char * token, word * curr)
{
    if (curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(token, a_word) == 0)
            return curr;
        else
            return checkPhrase(token, curr->next);
    }
    else
        return NULL;
  }
```

I expect this to be able to compile and work fine, but when I try to compile it, it tells me that `word * next` is a protected variable and I can't access it, referring to the line

```
return checkPhrase(token, curr->next);
```

Comment: why not use `std::string`?

Comment: @EdHeal It's an assignment, so c-strings are required :(

Comment: `texting` only gets access to its own `word`. Otherwise you could write `struct Break_protected : word { void do_bad_things(word *w); };` to render `protected` completely useless.

Comment: @Slava would I then have to use down casting to make the word pointer into a texting pointer? The next pointer is guaranteed to be pointing to a texting object

Comment: It is simpler to make `texting` a friend of `word` and I am not sure why it needs to inherit, just to get access? That is a wrong reason then.

Comment: `checkPhrase` seems to be confused as to which `word` it's operating on.  As it's written, every recursive call will be comparing against the same text.  It should probably either operate on `this` and not take its `curr` argument, or be static and operate only on its `curr` argument.

Comment: @nwp actually, if you static_cast `word *` to `Break_protected *` it would render it useless. Though it is UB I doubt it will break anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a child of a class access the data members of an object of the
>   derived class?

Yes, but its own members, not other object members. What you are accessing is the protected member of the object passed as parameter, and this object is from the base class, not the same class that this object, i.e., the `checkPhrase` method can access its own members from the base class if they are public or protected, but not the protected or private members of another object of the base class, even if this object is from the base class of this object.

As an example:

```
word * texting::checkPhrase(char * token, word * curr)
  {
      // this object
      this->next = nullptr; // this is valid
      next = nullptr; // this too

      // curr object
      curr->next = nulltr; // we are talking about an object of a different class and the variable has protected access.
  }
```

Comment: " the checkPhrase method can access its own members from the base class, but not the members of another object, even if this object is from the same class." actually is this really true?

Comment: @Slava if they are private definitely not. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I mean protected members from another object of the same class, they are actually accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You only have access to protected members of objects of your own class. This is an object of a base class, so no access.

The simplest solution here is to add a public getter function in the `word` class:

```
public:
    word* get_next() const
    { return next; }
```

and use it:

```
return checkPhrase(token, curr->get_next());
```

Also, you should make your current protected members in `word` private. Protected member variables are almost never a good idea. Protected function members are fine, but protected member variables are usually not.